# Should my sump pail be perforated?

Tags: drainage, sump-pump

I'm replacing the sump basin/liner in my home which is currently a perforated 5 gallon bucket surrounded by gravel.  I have an interior drain system that has two pipes terminating into the gravel pit area (but not into the basin itself - the water dumps into the gravel and through the holes in the bucket).  We have a high water table and the sump runs every few minutes on normal days.

My question is: should I replace the bucket with a solid liner, with openings for the drain pipe to go directly into the basin to be pumped out.... or should I use a perforated liner that allows water to come in in addition to the drain pipes?  It seems counter-intuitive to me to have the drain pipes empty into a basin with holes in it... but maybe I'm missing something and water needs to be allowed in in addition to the drains?

I really appreciate any advice you can give.  Thanks!

---

Oh my - two very different responses!  My thought was that if it the liner is sealed any additional water pressure would result in the perforated drain tile doing it's job "better" and bringing the water to the pit.  However, the response from Ed was exactly what I'm concerned about (the ground water causing the floor to leak).

If I use a perforated bucket it would surely always have water at the bottom because of the high water table.  Would it be okay to elevate the sump in the pit (using something like pavers) so that it's only emptying to a depth around 6" below the slab?  The problem now is it's constantly cycling to remove ground water that is over a foot below the slab.  I'm using a Zoeller without an adjustable float, so raising the pump itself is the only thing I can think of.

Thanks again for the responses.

---

Edited to add photo of current setup.  The current bucket top sits a couple of inches below the top of the slab... when I install the new basin I will make it level with the slab and fill with concrete.[image: Current Setup]

---

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You've created [two](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/96441/glen) different [accounts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/96471/portlandme); please use the  SE contact form to request that they be merged.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed many drain tile systems in Minnesota, and none of them used perforated pails. Really, you don't want to be collecting water from that far below your slab (and typically don't need to). All drainage should occur in the drainage medium via the tile.

If the drain tile (pipe) is perforated, there's no reason to have holes in your bucket unless you have a particular need to drain that deep. You're more likely to get sediment if you collect from down there as well.

*Response to your answer/comment:*

Your drainage medium (the clean rock I assume is below your slab) acts as the drainage path to the drain tile, which is simply a collector. If they're doing their respective jobs, no significant amount of water is present at the slab underside, and the question is rather moot. You don't need perforation unless you don't have drainage media under the slab, and if you don't, a perforated bucket only serves to allow drainage in the immediate vicinity of the bucket anyway. It won't keep your basement dry throughout.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply.  Apologies for posting my follow-up as an answer, I see how it works now.  There does appear to be clean rock as a drainage medium under the entire slab.  I guess I'll go with the solid bucket and see how things perform.  Are you able to address my follow-up regarding pump height?

Comment: There's no need to raise the pump since the pail will only collect from the level of the bottom of the inlet anyway, which is maybe 10-14 inches below the top of the pail/slab surface. That's the _weir_ of the system.

Comment: We disagree on this one, I have done this exact sump system on several homes in Oregon. Closing off the ability to keep the ground water away from the slab may at least cause damp floors and at worst cause puddling. The depth of the sump in this area needs to be at least 6-8 inches below the bottom of the slab. If some blocks were installed in the bottom of the bucket and there were no problems maybe the pump could be raised some more. I would tape some plastic on the floor and test for moisture in the slab now furthest away from the sump. Make the change and repeat the test.

Comment: Ed, the inlet to the pail in my scenario is 8-10 inches below the underside of the slab. If that isn't enough, I don't know how much would be.

Comment: Ed - Can you clarify on your point about "closing off the ability to keep ground water away from the slab...".  Isn't that exactly what the drain tile/pipe is intended to do?  Are you saying that in addition to what enters the drain tile, there would be more ground water that needs to enter the perforations in the basin to avoid seeping through the slab?

Comment: Why : "you don't want to be collecting water from that far below your slab" ? 8~10 inches is barely keeping the footings dry.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's relevant. Most interior and exterior drain tile is installed alongside the footings, so they're always "wet" anyway. The further you go the exponentially more water you'll have to pump with no real benefit.

Comment: I was always under the assumption that if I don't keep the water below my footings, if there ever is a real earthquake in Chicago, the 'soil' will liquefy... My five min of internet research came up empty for where the ideal water table is for below a slab or footings.

Comment: Glen, in my area we have a high ground water issue (Oregon), my comment about keeping the perforations there is because if they are sealed the water level will rise increasing the hydraulic pressure on your slab. I would do a plastic test. Tape a square of plastic to the floor maybe in several areas and pull it up the next day if the area looks wet or is wet with water dripping from the plastic any reduction in water removal may be bad. If the test shows dry put a couple of pavers under your pump once the pump starts cycling again do the plastic test again. It may be possible you don't need

Comment: Continued, the pump at all but I have seen a 6" slab shoot small sprinkler like jets of water ~30' from a sump pit, we dug down and found the home was on almost a foot of crushed rock. We dug a deeper pit packed with gravel and installed a pump and there wet floors were no more, we just needed to remove the water that was causing the problem. Do the plastic test first take photos , make changes and repeat the plastic test, more photos, more changes tests. At some point you might find you have to have the pump, I have found a level 6" below the slab in my area with rock under the slab is enough

Comment: @Ed - In those scenarios, did you have drain tile installed?  Again, I thought the purpose of those pipes were to collect rising water from hydraulic pressure and carry it away.  Without them, I totally understand the need to perforate.  With them, I am still at a loss.

Comment: The existing drain was there but there may have a spring under the slab by lowering the water level we were able to dry it out. I am not sure if there was a spring and the water table was very high we were hitting water at 18" below grade.

Answer (score 0):

The perforations are to allow ground water into the pit. If you seal this up your floor and walls will have more water pressure on them and may start leaking. Make sure to use a perforated liner.

Answer (score 0):

You're in a high water table area so I'll have to defer to the design of the system as is, as I picture it in my head (because I am *not* in one. See the old answer at the end, and the comments).

Assuming they'd reach into the new sump, cut holes for the drains but **do not** perforate it. If they aren't going to make it, either extend them or *do* perforate it.

Get a separate switch and put the pump as far down as it will go and the switch as high as possible, for less cycling. But put it on some bricks to prevent it sucking in sediment.

---

**Should my sump pail be perforated?** That depends on where your water table is.

Mine's low and my soil is clay, so I would perforate it.

Your water table is exceptionally high, so I wouldn't.

The thing you're complaining about is it cycling. It's cycling because it's in a 5 gal bucket, with an integral float.

A larger and sealed cistern, with a pump with a separate switch, wouldn't cycle so much.

---

A five gallon bucket for a sump in an area with a high water table... seriously? *There's your problem right there.*

Comment: You've said what you would do, but not why. What's the point of perforating in clay? You'll get very limited drainage and a lot of sediment.

Comment: @isherwood - For the foundation to be stable and the ground under it to not be subject to liquefaction. If your water table is 6" below your slab, that's a battle you can't win anyway - and shouldn't try to fight.

Comment: My point is that you cannot effectively drain a foundation with only clay under the slab. Perforated or not, the other side of the house will see no benefit.

Comment: @isherwood - My entire foundation is a cistern because it's clay; that's why I want holes. Basement's entirely below grade and I probably drain the entire block. But it takes a while to fill, again because it clay, so there's no cycle issues, also because it's in a hole *much* wider in diameter than a 5g bucket. If you're worried about hydo pressure, gah call somebody (!). But where I live it's just the difference between a somewhat wet floor or not. - Fourth opinion needed. Ideally from someone who lives even less then 500' above sea level.

Comment: I KNOW I need to upgrade from the 5 gallon bucket, which is why I asked the question about the new basin. I'd say the water table is currently ~10" below the top of the slab.   I don't know the soil make up, but from what I can tell there is at least several inches of gravel under the slab.  The drain tile has some water running through it almost constantly.  I will be routing those pipes into the basin.  If the basin is perforated it seems to me that the water will end up seeping OUT of the holes, back into the water table and then through the pipes again, resulting in unnecessary cycling.

Comment: @Glen - Edited. Honestly it's a lot of work to not get a better float switch situation going, which is what needs to change here, no mater what you do, for you to forget about this and live life happily.

Comment: But @isherwood had it right: *yours* shouldn't.

Comment: @Mazura - thank you.  This all makes sense.  I added a photo of the current setup.  I'm going to replace the bucket with a larger non-perforated basin, extend the pipes into the basin, and get an adjustable float switch which will allow me to empty the basin when the water reaches a level close to the pipe inlets.  Does that all sound right?

Comment: @Glen - That all sounds good, but I'm just still not sure where the ideal water level below a slab is. You're probably trying to actually use a cover and make it look pretty... *If* your floor is ever wet, I'd put the sump entirely below the incoming pipes (not even cut holes, just go below it all). It's easier to go little deeper now, and put more bricks to raise it, if you find you're just endlessly fighting ground water. But that looks pretty damn wet down there... If I dug a hole in my basement, it wouldn't be wet for at least half a foot.

Comment: That's not even low enough to be a sump; more like an exotic floor drain IMO. The bucket probably has holes in it; be sure whatever you put in has holes down to at least that level.  But I really would defer to someone in your area.